# Java - Fibonacci Prime Stuck Loop

Tags: java, fibonacci

My instructions are to write a program that utilizes more than just the MAIN method to find Fibonacci Prime numbers. But I am stuck in a while loop. I find 2 and 3 as Fibonacci Prime but I am stuck in the this position from there on.

```
    while ((b1 < f) && primeflag)
    {
        if (f % b1 == 0)
            primeflag= false;
```

Here is the entire source code.

```
public class stadfcs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Fibonacci Number and Prime Number Finder from 2 - 100000");
        int fb1 = 1; int fb2 = 1; int f =fb1 + fb2; 
        while (f <= 100000)
        {
            if (isPrime(f)) {
                System.out.println(f + " is a prime number and a Fibonacci Number!");
                fb1 = fb2;
                fb2 = f;                    
                f = fb1 + fb2;
            }
        }
    }
    private static boolean isPrime(int f) {
        boolean primeflag = true;
        if ((f%2==0) && (f>3))
            primeflag = false;
        int b1 = 3;
        while ((b1 < f) && primeflag)
        {
            if (f % b1 == 0)
                primeflag= false;
        }
        b1+=2;
        return primeflag;
    } 



    private static int fib(int fb1, int fb2) {
        return(fb1 + fb2);


    }

}
```

Comment: well `b1` is never incremented inside the while loop, so if `f` is ever greater than 3 that while loop will loop forever.

Comment: Please try to post formatted code that is compact and readable. You have unneccessary empty lines and inconsistent formatting. Formatting the code will make your code more readable to you and others. It will increase maintainability in the long run as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this loop:

```
    while (f <= 100000)
    {
        if (isPrime(f)) {
            System.out.println(f + " is a prime number and a Fibonacci Number!");
            fb1 = fb2;
            fb2 = f;                    
            f = fb1 + fb2;
        }
    }
```

Notice that if `f` isn't a prime number, then the value of `f` doesn't change inside the loop. This means that you'll get stuck in an infinite loop!

Did you mean to do something like this?

```
    while (f <= 100000)
    {
        if (isPrime(f)) {
            System.out.println(f + " is a prime number and a Fibonacci Number!");
        }
        fb1 = fb2;
        fb2 = f;                    
        f = fb1 + fb2;
    }
```

Comment: Also, `b1` isn't being incremented inside the while loop in `isPrime()`, so it'll loop forever, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
   fb1 = fb2;
   fb2 = f;                    
   f = fb1 + fb2;
```

Should be outside of { } 4 isn't prime and it just keeps going on never increasing

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this method:

```
while ((b1 < f) && primeflag)
    {
        if (f % b1 == 0)
            primeflag= false;
    }
```

but if b1 = 3 and f = 7, primeFlag = true, and it would never end because nothing is actually changing in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update b1 within the while loop. As it is currently, you're never increasing it causing it to remain stuck in the loop

```
private static boolean isPrime(int f) {
    boolean primeflag = true;
    if ((f%2==0) && (f>3))
        primeflag = false;
    int b1 = 3;
    while ((b1 < f) && primeflag)
    {
        if (f % b1 == 0) {
            primeflag= false;
        }
        b1+=2;
    }
    return primeflag;
}
```

On top of that, you'll also run into another infinite loop in your main while loop

```
while (f <= 100000)
    {
        if (isPrime(f)) {
            System.out.println(f + " is a prime number and a Fibonacci Number!");
            fb1 = fb2;
            fb2 = f;                    
            f = fb1 + fb2;
        }
    }
```

Notice that if f is not a prime number, that you will never escape that loop either. You should be doing something like this

```
while (f <= 100000)
    {
        if (isPrime(f)) {
            System.out.println(f + " is a prime number and a Fibonacci Number!");
        }
        fb1 = fb2;
        fb2 = f;                    
        f = fb1 + fb2;
    }
```